# Can I use the same AdWords developerToken and clientCustomerId for different accounts?

Tags: google-ads-api

I am making a web application that will automate some actions on Google AdWords. The web application can be used by anyone that has an AdWords account.

I am a bit puzzled by the AdWords API, as it is a different from other Google APIs, in terms that it needs two additional config parameters: `developerToken` and `clientCustomerId`, a per their documentation:

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/first-api-call

When constructing the AdWordsClient object, I need to provide the `developerToken` and `clientCustomerId`, in order to push data to AdWords.

My question is whether these two parameters (`developerToken`, `clientCustomerId`) need to be different for each user that will use my web application?

It seems that I am able to post data to different accounts with an unrelated `developerToken`, which does not make sense.

Can I get the `clientCustomerId` from an API endpoint, so I don't require my users to manually input tokens and ids to the web app, and do the complete authentication with oAuth?

My code is working, I am asking more of the philosophy why I need these two parameters, and if I can avoid asking the user to manually copy them from the AdWords dashboard into my application?

Answer (score 1):

The developer token identifies a given Adwords API developer and is used for RMF enforcement, rate limiting and the like. As you mentioned, this is different from other Google APIs, which I think has to do with the fact that it's not a publicly available API. You always have to use the developer token that was given to you as part of your API sign-up process and are not allowed to use another developer's one (thus there's no possibility to have a user of your application enter it on their own).

The `clientCustomerId` parameter refers to the specific Google Ads account that you want to interact with. As a given user (identified by the OAuth2 access token that you include in your request) might have access to a whole lot of different accounts, this always needs to be included.

As for how to obtain a list of accessible account given a user's credentials, you can use the [CustomerService.getCustomers](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/CustomerService#getcustomers) endpoint for that purpose. Quoting the docs, it will "return details of all the customers directly accessible by the user authenticating the call."

Comment: Regarding the developerToken, it is obtained from the customer-facing Adwords dashboard, not the Google Developers Dashboard where you register the application. So that is why I assumed it is per Adwords account/customer.

Comment: Yes, the developer token is bound the the Google Ads MCC that you specify in your API signup application. I would assume this is for historic reasons as the Adwords API predates the Cloud Consoles. I think it was available starting 2005 :)